# Can't import Scipy on my anaconda enviroment

Tags: python, scipy, anaconda

I was trying to import `scipy` on my anaconda enviroment. But when i am working on visual studio code and powershell it gives me following error but works totally fine on jupyter notebook. what's going wrong?

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\amiftekher\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py", line 156, in <module>
    from . import fft
  File "C:\Users\amiftekher\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\fft\__init__.py", line 76, in <module>
    from ._basic import (
  File "C:\Users\amiftekher\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\fft\_basic.py", line 1, in <module>
    from scipy._lib.uarray import generate_multimethod, Dispatchable
  File "C:\Users\amiftekher\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\_lib\uarray.py", line 27, in <module>
    from ._uarray import *
  File "C:\Users\amiftekher\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\_lib\_uarray\__init__.py", line 114, in <module>
    from ._backend import *
  File "C:\Users\amiftekher\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\_lib\_uarray\_backend.py", line 15, in <module>
    from . import _uarray  # type: ignore
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Scipy and python version information

> ```
> Python : 3.7.6
> scipy : 1.4.1
> ```

Comment: Can you give us information how you installed scipy.

Comment: I installed scipy using `pip install scipy`. It works fine on jupyter notebook.

Comment: Since you are using anaconda, the conda package for scipy may be a better choice for you: `pip uninstall scipy`  and `conda install scipy`

Comment: still gave the same error message.